# Why i'm getting error that the variable need to be static?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a top of a class file i added a class:

```
public class World
{
    public List<Continent> continents;

    public World()
    {
        continents = new List<Continent>();
    }
}

public class Continent
{
    public string name;
    public List<Country> countries { get; set; }

    public Continent()
    {
        name = string.Empty;
        countries = new List<Country>();
    }
}

public class Country
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> imageUrls { get; set; }
    public Country()
    {
        name = string.Empty;
        imageUrls = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

When using it in form1:

```
foreach (ExtractImages.Continent continent in ExtractImages.World.continents)
{
    Console.WriteLine(continent.name);
    foreach (ExtractImages.Country country in continent.countries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(country.name);
        foreach (string imageUri in country.imageUrls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(imageUri);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error in form1 on:

```
ExtractImages.World.continents
```

On the line:

```
foreach (ExtractImages.Continent continent in ExtractImages.World.continents)
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ExtractImages.World.continents'

Update

First in the class file i'm using the World before using it in form1:
When in Form1 i create new instance for World it will be all empty.

```
public void ImagesLinks()
        {
            try
            {
                int counter = 0;

                foreach (string countryCode in countriescodes)
                {
                    Country country = new Country();
                    country.name = countriesnames[counter];
                    List<string> imageUrl = new List<string>();
                    counter++;
                    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < DatesAndTimes.Count(); cnt++)
                    {
                        string imageUrlIrTrue = firstUrlPart + countryCode + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[cnt] + thirdUrlPart + "true";
                        string imageUrlIrFalse = firstUrlPart + countryCode + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[cnt] + thirdUrlPart + "false";
                        imageUrl.Add(imageUrlIrTrue);
                        imageUrl.Add(imageUrlIrFalse);

                        if (cnt == 9)
                        {
                            cnt = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    country.imageUrls = imageUrl;
                    Europe.countries.Add(country);

                }
                world.continents.Add(Europe);
            }
```

This is in Form1 now:

```
ExtractImages.World world = new ExtractImages.World();
            foreach (ExtractImages.Continent continent in world.continents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(continent.name);
                foreach (ExtractImages.Country country in continent.countries)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(country.name);
                    foreach (string imageUri in country.imageUrls)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(imageUri);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You are calling it like a static object when it is not static.

Comment: Because you're using it as a static class. You're not asking for `.continents` on an *instance* of the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create first an instance of your class, since `continents` are an *instance field* and **not** a `static field` and then access `continents`. However, keep in mind that in you constructor you just create an empty list. You don't supply any list of `continenets`. So each time you create a new World object, `continents` would be an empty list of `Continent` objects. You should supply something different there than an empty list, since the `foreach` you have in your post would be meaningless.

```
var world = new World();

foreach (var continent in world.continents)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention i'm using the World in the class file first so if i create new instance of World in form1 it will be empty. I will update my question.

Comment: @DanielDejunior not a problem. You say you use the `World`. How? Don't you have created an instance of this class?